# Run shell script(.csh) in cygwin using python

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin

I have created a python tool which generates shell script & run it using command

subprocess.Popen("csh -l -c " + os.environ["TEMP"] + "\qa_tool\oos_script_generator.csh")

This runs in c-shell. Is there any way I can run same script in cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out by now, but I believe tcsh is available in the package list, have you tried installing it to see if it fits your need?

Comment: I have tcsh installed but like csh which takes any command with syntax csh -l -c "command/script", it is not possible to pass command to tcsh.